# How do I call SharePoint 2010 REST API from C# if that site has claims based auth?

Tags: web-services, rest

For example, this site is secured via Claims Auth (It has both FBA and Windows Auth).  My guess my issue is security.  I ultimately want to use the credentials that my IIS app pool is running under.  I don't have SharePoint referenced on purpose as I want to do this purely via REST (or asmx if that doesn't work).  I simply want to read data from a list.

http://www.yoursite.com/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/SampleList

Comment: What reason do you want to do this as the app pool identity?

Comment: Also, what error are you getting? Do you have ADO.NET Data Services installed on the server? Can you access that URL when logged on locally to the server?

Comment: It just times out.  I want to have the windows auth account as the authentication method, so whatever the IIS app pool is running on.  I don't have ADO.NET data services installed.

Comment: You'll need ADO.NET Data Services installed on the server in order to enable the REST interface. I would also suggest that using the app pool identity to access the list is an insecure method, as your application could be hijacked and the URL substituted, exposing potentially vulnerable information also on that web application. Consider creating a dedicated, restricted user on the site collection specific for your application.

Comment: So SharePoint already has ADO.NET Services. The REST api works because I can use it directly in the browser.  I'm trying to call from a completely separate server.  I don't need it installed there, correct?  It only needs to be installed on the server that is serving up the REST API

Comment: Correct, it only needs to be on the server that hosts SharePoint itself. I assume you can browse the site as normal (without the _vti_bin bit, just the content) from the remote system?